# How to multithred correctly? UIAlertView is not displayed, only gray screen

Tags: ios, multithreading, uialertview, dispatch, performselector

i have implemented textToSpeech in my project and want to display an alertview while text is spoken. here i am calling the methods for textToSpeech:

```
//-----before TTS starts i try to display alertView with Cancelbutton  
//[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(alertWhileTTS) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES]; //gray view and no alertview
//[self performSelector:@selector(alertWhileTTS)];  //gray view and no alertview
//[self alertWhileTTS];  //gray view and no alertview

//this part here is blocking, no gray screen, 
//after TTS is ready, the alertView is displayed
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //Update UI if you have to
        [self alertWhileTTS];
    });


[[self view] setNeedsDisplay];
[self synthesizeInBackground];
[queue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished];
[self setIsSpeaking: false];
[[self view] setNeedsDisplay];
```

Here the synthesizeInBackground method(*in method* `synthesize` *starts the TTS*):

```
- (void) synthesizeInBackground {
    queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self 
    selector:@selector(synthesize) object:nil];

    [queue addOperation: operation];
}
```

While TTS i want to display an alertView with `cancel` button. But in my case i am only getting a gray screen without the alertView.

**How can i call alertWhileTTS correctly**, so the alertView gets displayed?

here is the content of alertWhileTTS:

```
- (void) alertWhileTTS {
UIAlertView *inboxRead = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Inbox tts..."
                                                    message:nil
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Abbrechen"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease];
inboxRead.tag = 997;

[inboxRead show];
}
```

**UPDATE** see my solution, that works:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(alertWhileTTS) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, (unsigned long)NULL), ^(void) {
        [[self view] setNeedsDisplay];
        [self synthesizeInBackground];
        [queue waitUntilAllOperationsAreFinished];
        [self setIsSpeaking: false];
        [[self view] setNeedsDisplay];

    });
```

Comment: It's been a while since manual memory management, but I don't think you are supposed to release the alert view so quickly.  Try autoreleasing it instead.  Also make sure to do it on the main thread.  All UI changes must be done there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the alertWithTTsTo

```
UIAlertView *inboxRead = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Inbox tts..."
                                                    message:nil
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Abbrechen"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil] autoRelease];
inboxRead.tag = 997;

[inboxRead show];
```

Also dont forget to call the function `alertWhileTTS` from the main ui thread
By doing

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //Update UI if you have to
        [self alertWhileTTS];
    });
```

Comment: i have added autorelease, like borrrden said, also tried to call it on mainthread. also tried with your `dispatch_async` code, but now there is no gray screen. the alertView appears after TTS is done.

Comment: Can you show us where you call alertWhileTTS? can you put the calling function?

Comment: see my post i am calling it before `[[self view] setNeedsDisplay];` i have commented the code.

Comment: Please try the following instead of 
[self performSelector:@selector(alertWhileTTS)];  call 
[self performSelector:@selector(alertWhileTTS) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];

Comment: i have update my code again. also writed what is happening. i cant understand why the alertView appears after TTS.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12167/discussion-between-omar-abdelhafith-and-brush51)

Comment: see my updated answer. i am calling at first the alertView, after that in `dispatch async` the text to speech methods. thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Automatic Reference Counting (ARC) As that will release everything automatically. As borrden stated, you are (presumably) releasing the UIAlertView to quickly.